# css animation runs when not :focus but also when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

i am doing an animation for a search input field. i am making it bigger when it is in :focus and smaller when it is not in :focus and it is working fine i am having an issue with the animation happening when the page loads when it is not in focus. i know i can solve it by doing autofocus in the input field. here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dj33n5js/):
html:

```
<body>
<!--menu start here-->
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="logo">
        Logo goes here
        </div>
        <div class="search">
            <input type="search" class="bar">
            <input type="submit" class="submit">
        </div>
        <ul class="ul">
            <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<!--menu end here-->
</body>
```

here is the css:

```
html,body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.menu{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    margin:0;
    background:#e6e6e6;
}
.logo{
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:250px;
    border-right:2px solid white;
}
.search{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}
.bar{
    display:inline;
    width:150px;
    padding:2px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:#e6e6e6;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.bar:focus{
    outline:none;
    width:250px;
    animation-name:wider;
    animation-duration:0.5s;
    padding:7px;
    background:white;
}
.bar:not(:focus){
    animation-name:tighter;
    animation-duration:0.5s;
    display:inline;
    width:150px;
    padding:2px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:#e6e6e6;
}
.submit{
    padding:7px;
    display:inline;
    background-color:green;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid green;
    color:lightgreen;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.submit:focus{
    outline:none;
}
.ul{
    float:right;
    display:inline;
}
.menuitem{
    display:inline;
}
.menuitem>a{
    padding:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#7a7a7a;
}
.menuitem>a:hover{
    background:#5c5c5c;
    color:#e6e6e6;
}
@keyframes wider{
    from{
        width:150px;
        padding:2px;
        background:#e6e6e6;
    }
    to{
        background:white;
        width:250px;
        padding:7px;
    }
}
@keyframes tighter{ 
    from{
        background:white;
        width:250px;
        padding:7px;
    }
    to{
        width:150px;
        padding:2px;
        background:#e6e6e6;
    }
}
```

or if u prefer a code snippet:

```css
html,body{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
.menu{
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 margin:0;
 background:#e6e6e6;
}
.logo{
 float:left;
 height:50px;
 width:250px;
 border-right:2px solid white;
}
.search{
 display:inline;
 float:left;
 padding:10px;
}
.bar{
 display:inline;
 width:150px;
 padding:2px;
 border-radius:5px;
 background:#e6e6e6;
 border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.bar:focus{
 outline:none;
 width:250px;
 animation-name:wider;
 animation-duration:0.5s;
 padding:7px;
 background:white;
}
.bar:not(:focus){
 animation-name:tighter;
 animation-duration:0.5s;
 display:inline;
 width:150px;
 padding:2px;
 border-radius:5px;
 background:#e6e6e6;
}
.submit{
 padding:7px;
 display:inline;
 background-color:green;
 border-radius:5px;
 border:1px solid green;
 color:lightgreen;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.submit:focus{
 outline:none;
}
.ul{
 float:right;
 display:inline;
}
.menuitem{
 display:inline;
}
.menuitem>a{
 padding:15px;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#7a7a7a;
}
.menuitem>a:hover{
 background:#5c5c5c;
 color:#e6e6e6;
}
@keyframes wider{
 from{
  width:150px;
  padding:2px;
  background:#e6e6e6;
 }
 to{
  background:white;
  width:250px;
  padding:7px;
 }
}
@keyframes tighter{ 
 from{
  background:white;
  width:250px;
  padding:7px;
 }
 to{
  width:150px;
  padding:2px;
  background:#e6e6e6;
 }
}
```

```html
<body>
<!--menu start here-->
 <div class="menu">
  <div class="logo">
  Logo goes here
  </div>
  <div class="search">
   <input type="search" class="bar">
   <input type="submit" class="submit">
  </div>
  <ul class="ul">
   <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
   <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
   <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
<!--menu end here-->
</body>
```

when the page first loads u can see the animation happening. is there anyway to do this using css only ? if not i don't mind using javascript or jQuery (i am decent in them both)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now what's causing the issue you're seeing is that the tighter animation will trigger right away since `.bar:not(:focus)` will be "active" right away.

I would also say it's a bit overkill to use keyframe animation to do what you are trying to achieve. A simple css3 transition would be plenty and also doesn't cause the issue you're seeing:

```
.bar{
    display:inline;
    width:150px;
    padding:2px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:#e6e6e6;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    transition: all .5s; /* Transition animates everything that's specified in .bar:focus */
}
.bar:focus{
    outline:none;
    width:250px;
    padding:7px;
    background:white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3pk1ydvz/

Comment: can u explain what does all do in transition ?

Comment: The *all* identifier tells the transition to transitionally animate *all* (any) CSS properties when the property's value is changed. You could of course specify exactly which CSS properties you want to set the transition to. This can either be done by changing *all* to whichever CSS property (single) and if you need to specify multiple properties use transition-property, e.g `transition-property: opacity, left, top, height;` You can find more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Answer (score 1):

### Have you tried using :blur instead of not:focus?

Have you specified transitions for each web browser?

Example

```
    #id_of_element {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

---

'All' in transition pertains to Height, opacity, and ease. So the properties will all transition in 1s (As shown in above code)

Comment: i did when u click on it it gets bigger but when u click away it gets smaller but doesn't do the animation

Answer (score 1):

Try with transition rather than animation.

You don't need .bar:not(focus), that's basically the same as .bar

```css
html,body{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
.menu{
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 margin:0;
 background:#e6e6e6;
}
.logo{
 float:left;
 height:50px;
 width:250px;
 border-right:2px solid white;
}
.search{
 display:inline;
 float:left;
 padding:10px;
}
.bar{
 display:inline;
 width:150px;
 padding:2px;
 border-radius:5px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
 background:#e6e6e6;
  transition:all ease 0.5s;
}

.bar:focus{
 outline:none;
 width:250px;
 padding:7px;
 background:white;
}
.submit{
 padding:7px;
 display:inline;
 background-color:green;
 border-radius:5px;
 border:1px solid green;
 color:lightgreen;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.submit:focus{
 outline:none;
}
.ul{
 float:right;
 display:inline;
}
.menuitem{
 display:inline;
}
.menuitem>a{
 padding:15px;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#7a7a7a;
}
.menuitem>a:hover{
 background:#5c5c5c;
 color:#e6e6e6;
}
```

```html
<body>
<!--menu start here-->
 <div class="menu">
  <div class="logo">
  Logo goes here
  </div>
  <div class="search">
   <input type="search" class="bar">
   <input type="submit" class="submit">
  </div>
  <ul class="ul">
   <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
   <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
   <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
<!--menu end here-->
</body>
```

Updated jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/dj33n5js/3](https://jsfiddle.net/dj33n5js/3/)

Comment: u were a tad bit too late sorry i couldnt accept ur answer but this works

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the initial style to the `.bar` element.
As I understand the styles on `.bar` itself should be the same as on `.bar:not(focus)`.

Comment: i copied the style for the :not(:focus) from the .bar and i changed it